# VBA http.send not working

Tags: vba, excel

I found very usefull VBA code using csv file on yahoo.finance website. It works fine on my PC at home, but when I try it at work it freezes in line:

**Http.Send**

Is sending http requests just blocked or can be other reason ? Is there any way of solving it ?

Code and data from excel file below:

```
Private Sub REFRESH_Click()

Dim W As Worksheet
Set W = ActiveSheet

Dim Last As Integer
Last = W.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
If Last = 1 Then Exit Sub

Dim Symbols As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To Last

Symbols = Symbols & W.Range("A" & i).Value & "+"

Next i

Cells(10, 10).Value = Symbols

Symbols = Left(Symbols, Len(Symbols) - 1)

Dim URL As String
URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" & Symbols & "&f=snl1ab"

Cells(11, 10).Value = URL


Dim Http As New WinHttpRequest
Http.Open "GET", URL, False
Http.Send


Dim Resp As String
Resp = Http.ResponseText

Dim Lines As Variant
Lines = Split(Resp, vbNewLine)

Dim Sline As String
Dim Values As Variant
For i = 0 To UBound(Lines)
Sline = Lines(i)
If InStr(Sline, ",") = 0 Then End
Values = Split(Sline, ",")

W.Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Values(1)
W.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 2)
W.Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Values(UBound(Values) - 1)
W.Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Values(UBound(Values))

Next i


End Sub
```

Data in Excel file:

Symbol  Name    Price   Ask Bid
IBM
USB
MSFT

I would be very grateful for help.
Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

Excel can import it's own data. It doesn't need your help.

Your code omits any error checking. Therefore whatever is happening you aren't reading it.

So to import web pages in Excel, Alt + D, D, W.

You can import to a new sheet and just refer to it on main sheet. (not useful for CSV, they go direct to main sheet).

Here's some code that does error checking.

Put the following lines into a text file. Name it safetyscanner.vbs and put on desktop.

For 32 Bit Windows

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
 On Error Resume Next
 Set File = WScript.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
 File.Open "GET", "http://definitionupdates.microsoft.com/download/definitionupdates/safetyscanner/x86/msert.exe", False
 File.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; BCD2000; BCD2000)"
 File.Send
 If err.number <> 0 then 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "Error getting file" 
  Outp.writeline "==================" 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "Error " & err.number & "(0x" & hex(err.number) & ") " & err.description 
  Outp.writeline "Source " & err.source 
  Outp.writeline "" 
  Outp.writeline "HTTP Error " & File.Status & " " & File.StatusText
  Outp.writeline  File.getAllResponseHeaders
  Outp.writeline Arg(1)
 End If

On Error Goto 0

 Set BS = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
 BS.type = 1
 BS.open
 BS.Write File.ResponseBody
 BS.SaveToFile "c:\users\safetyscanner.exe", 2
```